# Compare maps and update one with intersecting keys with lowest value at key

Tags: java, hashmap

I needed this solution for a LeetCode question, 1002: Find Common Characters, and I didn't see a proper solution.

The operation I needed was to update map "a" with the intersecting keys between "a" and "b" and set the value of the keys to the lower value of the two.

Although the use case of this is slim, it is still nice to have a solution.

```
class Solution {
    public List<String> commonChars(String[] A) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Character, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Character, Integer> b = new HashMap<>();
        List<Character> removeChars = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //base: populate map a so you can compare with next string in A[]
        
        for(char c : A[0].toCharArray()){
            int count = a.getOrDefault(c, 0);
            a.put(c, count+1);
        }
        
        /*
        compare each character in A[] to keys in map a
        
            if contains
                put character in map b and incremnt count
            else
                remove from map a
            
        update map a with whatever has smaller value for each key
        clear map b
            
        iterate
            
        put all keys in list for how many values it has
        
        */
        for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
            for(char c : A[i].toCharArray()){
                if(a.containsKey(c)){
                    int count = b.getOrDefault(c, 0);
                    b.put(c, count+1);
                } else
                    a.remove(c);
            }


            /*
             Here I need to compare the keys to each map
                 - If they were present in both, take the lower value
                 - If not, then I needed to remove the key from map "a"
            */


            for(char c : removeChars){
                a.remove(c);
            }
            b.clear();
        }
        for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : a.entrySet()){
            char key = entry.getKey();
            int val = entry.getValue();
            for(int i = 0; i < val; i++){
                list.add(String.valueOf(key));
            }
        }
        return list;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an Entry set from map a
- Iterate through the entries
- Set the key and value to variables for simple comparison

  - If there is an intersection between keys, overwrite map a with the lower value of the key
  - Else add the key to a list of characters

*You cannot remove keys from the entry set during looping, instead store the keys to be removed in a list and remove them after the loop occurs.*

```
Map<Character, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
Map<Character, Integer> b = new HashMap<>();
List<Character> removeChars = new ArrayList<>();

for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry1 : a.entrySet()){
    char keyA = entry1.getKey();
    int valA = entry1.getValue();
    if(b.containsKey(keyA)){
        int valB = b.get(keyA);
        a.put(keyA, Math.min(valA, valB));
     }else
        removeChars.add(keyA);
}
```

### For General Usage

```
Map<Key, Value> mapA = new HashMap<Key, Value>();
Map<Key, Value> mapB = new HashMap<Key, Value>();
List<T> remove = new ArrayList<T>();

for(Map.Entry<Ket, value> entry : mapA.entrySet()){
    Key key = entry.getKey();
    Value valA = entry.getValue();
    
    if(mapB.containskey(key)){
        int valB = mapB.get(key);
        mapA.put(key, Math.min(valA, valB);
    } else
        remove.add(keyA);
}
```

Comment: But if you are evil and do not like your junior colleagues, or want to confuse the inexperienced beginners, solve the whole thing in one line: `mapA.forEach((k,v) -> mapA.put(k , Math.min(mapB.getOrDefault(k, v), v)));`

Comment: @Eritrean damn you're right, the less readable solution is always preferred for job security.